# How do I upgrade Rubygems in Bluemix?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ibm-cloud

How do I upgrade Rubygems in Bluemix? I'm getting this message:

> Rubygems 2.0.14.1 is not threadsafe, so your gems must be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.

and since I have a lot of gems, I'd really like to use this feature.
I'm using Ruby buildpack version 1.6.7 and Ruby 2.0.0.

Comment: Probably the same way as anywhere else - `gem update --system`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using newer Ruby version 2.2.2 in newer buildpack.

Answer (score 7):

```
gem install rubygems-update
update_rubygems
# gem update --system # in fact, you are done on the previous step
```

Comment: I can't really run my own commands while deploying application in Bluemix. Solved it by using newer Ruby version 2.2.2

Answer (score 3):

Use `gem update --system` as stated [here](http://blog.rubygems.org/2013/09/09/2.1.0-released.html)